# Getting single output

Tags: python

Where do I go wrong?
I'm connecting to a zabbix server. Per host I get 9 lines with output but I only need the last clocked value.

This is the code I'm using.

```
import sys
import logging
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI, ZabbixAPIException

zapi = ZabbixAPI("http://10.31.17.20/zabbix")
zapi.login("admin", "zabbix")

hostgroups  = '44'

hglookup = zapi.host.get(output=['extend'])
item = zapi.item.get (output=['extend'])
if hglookup:
    if item:
        host = zapi.host.get(output='extend', groupids= hostgroups)
        item = zapi.item.get(output=['key_','lastclock','lastvalue'], filter=   {'groupids': hostgroups,'key_':'vfs.fs.size[/,total]'})

for h in host:
    for i in item:
        print h ['host'] ,  i ['key_'],  i ['lastvalue'],  i ['lastclock']
```

### Output example

```
#host vfs.fs.size[/,total] 41083600896 1493120486
#host vfs.fs.size[/,total] 12988710912 1493119362
#host vfs.fs.size[/,total] 12988710912 1493119389
#host vfs.fs.size[/,total] 12988710912 1493119428
#host  vfs.fs.size[/,total] 12988710912 1493119475
#host  vfs.fs.size[/,total] 18881585152 1493119514
#host  vfs.fs.size[/,total] 18881585152 1493119545
#host  vfs.fs.size[/,total] 21462233088 1493119862
#host  vfs.fs.size[/,total] 18881585152 1493120574
#host1  vfs.fs.size[/,total] 41083600896 1493120486
#host1  vfs.fs.size[/,total] 12988710912 1493119362
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Erm, well, you're looping through all of the hosts and printing out every one. It sound like that's not what you want to do? What is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is:   
host1 vfs.fs.size[/,total] 12988710912
host2 vfs.fs.size[/,total] 41083600896
etc..

Rgds,

John

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zabbix, but I don't see anything linking elements in `item` with elements in `host`. You're effectively doing an outer join on those two lists.